# Não consigo salvar o cadastro

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, servidor

Buneas pessoal, eu não sei mexer em C#, por isso vou fazendo o programa seguindo dicas no youtube e outros tutoriais que encontro, porém me deparei com um erro que eu ainda não achei como resolver...

Toda vez que clico em cadastrar o programa me manda isso

> ```
>     internal void Insert(int p, string p_2, string p_3, int p_4, string p_5, System.Drawing.Image image, string p_6)
>     {
>         throw new System.NotImplementedException();
>     }
> ```

Porém não tenho a menor idéia de como resolver, o meu code está logo a seguir, se alguém souber me ajudar agradeceria muito, isso é só um programinha que estou querendo fazer para minha mãe usar no trabalho dela para facilitar

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2010 C# com SQL Server, se isso faz alguma diferença

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ficha_de_Anamnese.anamneseDBDataSetTableAdapters;
using System.IO;

namespace Ficha_de_Anamnese
{
    public partial class cadastrodeusuario : Form
    {
        public cadastrodeusuario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Limpar()
        {
            imgpath.Clear();
            senha.Clear();
            confsenha.Clear();
            resposta.Clear();
            email.Clear();
            login.Clear();
            nome.Clear();
            pergunta.SelectedIndex = -1;
            if (imgbox.Image != null)
            {
                imgbox.Image.Dispose();
                imgbox.Image = null;
            }
        }

        private void cadastrodeusuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'anamneseDBDataSet.userDB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.userDBTableAdapter.Fill(this.anamneseDBDataSet.userDB);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'anamneseDBDataSet.pergDB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.pergDBTableAdapter.Fill(this.anamneseDBDataSet.pergDB);
            Limpar();

        }

        private void btn_voltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Inicio back = new Inicio();
            back.Show();
        }

        private void btn_cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rEMail = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");
            if (nome.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo NOME deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                nome.Focus();
            }
            else if (email.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo E-MAIL deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                email.Focus();
            }
            else if (!rEMail.IsMatch(email.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("E-Mail inválido!", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                email.SelectAll();
                email.Focus();
            }
            else if (login.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo LOGIN deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                login.Focus();
            }
            else if ((login.Text.Length < 6) || (login.Text.Length > 10))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O login deve ter entre 6 e 10 dígitos");
                login.Focus();
            }
            else if (senha.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo SENHA deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                senha.Focus();
            }
            else if ((senha.Text.Length < 5) || (senha.Text.Length > 15))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A senha deve ter entre 5 e 15 dígitos");
                senha.Focus();
            }
            else if (confsenha.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo REPETIR SENHA deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                confsenha.Focus();
            }
            else if (senha.Text != confsenha.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("As senhas não são iguais!", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                confsenha.Focus();
            }
            else if (pergunta.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você deve escolher uma pergunta", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                pergunta.Focus();
            }
            else if (resposta.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O campo RESPOSTA deve ser preenchido", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                resposta.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                userDBTableAdapter uta = new userDBTableAdapter();
                uta.Insert(int.Parse(login.Text.ToString()), nome.Text, senha.Text, int.Parse(pergunta.SelectedValue.ToString()), resposta.Text, imgbox.Image, email.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Usuário Registrado com sucesso!", "Ficha de Anamnese - Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void btn_limpar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Limpar();
        }

        private void imgbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imgpath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                imgbox.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                //Read Image File into Image object.
                Image img = Image.FromFile(imgbox.ImageLocation);
                //ImageConverter Class convert Image object to Byte array.
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
            }
        }

        private void login_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 08 && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Delete)
            {
               e.Handled = true;
               MessageBox.Show("O campo LOGIN só aceita números.", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Programar sem estudar básico da linguagem? é um caminho dificil demais.

Comment: eu já resolvi deletando e refazendo tudo novamente, não sei se aqui tem isso de fechar tópico, mas se tiver, já podem fechar

Answer (score 1):

Henrique, isso não é um erro. A exceção é proposital justamente para indicar que seu programa não está completo.

```
internal void Insert(int p, string p_2, string p_3, int p_4, string p_5, System.Drawing.Image image, string p_6)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Esse é um método que parece muito ter sido gerado automaticamente e você precisa implementar a sua lógica. Ou ainda pode ser que seja uma funcionalidade não implementada em alguma biblioteca que esteja usando. (É mais provável que seja a primeira opção)

Comment: mas no caso, como eu disse ali, eu não sei mexer em C# (ou qualquer outra linguagem), eu vou fazendo de acordo com youtube e outros tutoriais, sabe me dizer se tem como eu descobrir de uma forma simples o que está acontecendo?

Comment: @HenriqueSP Talvez você não tenha chegado nesse ponto do tutorial que está seguindo ou acabou pulando alguma etapa. Edite sua pergunta adicionando o link para o seu material de referência.